# "Parameter "toolsPath" cannot be null." when calling MSBuildWorkspace.OpenProjectAsync()

Tags: c#, msbuild, roslyn

I have a Visual Studio solution with many C# projects. I'm currently trying to build a new C# project in that solution that builds and runs project 1, but I'm getting the runtime error when calling `MSBuildWorkspace.OpenProjectAsync`:

> Parameter "toolsPath" cannot be null.'

I'm not sure what parameter this refers to. My code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;

namespace RunAllProjects
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            using MSBuildWorkspace ws = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
            var project = await ws.OpenProjectAsync("../../../../1/1.csproj");
            Console.WriteLine(project.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea where this error could be coming from? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you call MSBuildWorkspace.Create(), call `MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults()`. There's instructions for how to use MSBuildLocator [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/updating-an-existing-application?view=vs-2022#use-microsoftbuildlocator).

Comment: Thank you so much! Missed that requirement.

Comment: We probably need to update our docs. :-)